# function do not delete the array item when press delete button

Tags: ios, swift

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath:    NSIndexPath) {
if editingStyle == .Delete {
        allNotes.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```

// this is the note class

```
var allNotes:[Note] = []
var currentNoteIndex:Int = -1
var noteTable:UITableView?

let kAllNotes:String = "notes"

class Note:NSObject {

var date:String
var note:String


override init() {


    date = NSDate().description
    note = ""


}


func dictionary() -> NSDictionary {
    return ["note":note, "date": date]
}


class func savedNotes() {


    var aDictionary:[NSDictionary] = []
    for var i:Int = 0; i < allNotes.count; i++ {
        aDictionary.append(allNotes[i].dictionary())

    }


    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(aDictionary, forKey: kAllNotes)


}

class func loadNotes() {

    var defaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var savedData:[NSDictionary]? = defaults.objectForKey(kAllNotes) as? [NSDictionary]
    if let data:[NSDictionary] = savedData {
        for var i:Int = 0; i < data.count; i++ {

            var n:Note = Note()
            n.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(data[i] as [NSObject : AnyObject])
            allNotes.append(n)

        }

    }



}

}
```

this is the function , but it won't delete the item on the array permanently,  temporary remove from the table view. when relaunch the simulator , still table view show removed items

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        allNotes.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(allNotes, forKey: kAllNotes)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```

when i update like this any try to delete the array item , shows a thread error

Comment: You need to save the changes to disk so that it will keep during relaunch

Comment: how can i do it , please explain, Thank you !!!

Comment: I think saving notes into `NSUserDefaults ` is bad idea. instead of that you can save it to plist or any other database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will remove only from your `allNotes` array at run time because your are not deleting in from the memory from where your getting value for your `allNotes` array.

For example if you are reading your array from plist file from memory then you have to delete that item from that plist file too.

So when you relaunch your app your `allNotes` array will not get that deleted item from your plist. And it will not display your deleted item.

Comment: tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(allNotes, forKey: kAllNotes)    but when i used this and try to delete item , system crashed :(

Comment: show some more code related with your `allNotes ` array in your question.